# How to create custom installer for Adobe Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

I want to build my installer of the Adobe Brackets source code. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to generate the Windows MSI installer for Brackets (like the ones available at http://download.brackets.io), check out the [installer README.MD documentation](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/blob/master/installer/win/README.MD).  As a prerequisite, make sure you are able to [build the brackets-shell binaries](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-brackets-shell) first.